# Listbox population sometimes shows number instead of text value

Tags: sql, excel, vba

[image]
I have a listbox in a userform. I use a SQL query to pull data and then populate the listbox. When I look at the query in SQL, it is fine and shows text in those fields. The listbox is showing these numbers though, 4 and 5, what I am assuming is the column name or fields value?

It should say "Landfill/Wellfield" and "O2 levels", so it is not a text length issue. This is all test data. The last column correctly shows "Sparkplugs/Ignition System"

The listbox has 7 columns of data.

Code for the listbox population:

```
lbx_SSM.Clear
Do Until XL_RSet.EOF = True
    For i = 1 To 7
        If i = 1 Then
            lbx_SSM.AddItem (XL_RSet.Fields(columnName(i)))
        Else
            If Not (XL_RSet.Fields(columnName(i)) = "Null") 
                Then lbx_SSM.List(lbx_SSM.ListCount - 1, i - 1) =(XL_RSet.Fields(columnName(i)))
            End If
    Next i
    XL_RSet.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is causing the current issue, but if you want columnheaders in your listbox, then you should query to a listObject on an `xlVeryHidden` sheet and let `listbox.columnheads=true`, and `listbox.rowsource=sheet.name & "!" & listobject.DataBodyRange.Address`

Comment: Thanks, interesting to know. But yeah I don't really need headers. I need these numbers to go away! XD

Comment: Are you performing any modification to either your recordset before or your listbox after population?

Comment: Nope, after the code you see and the listbox is populated, the routine ends. There are options to filter the data, those buttons set a new SQL query with filters and do the same listbox code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I am not sure what the issue was, but using this to populate the listbox instead of the above does not cause the issue. I've used that first code all the time before so it might be a Fields() issue or something. See below:

```
XL_RSet.Open 
XL_RSet.MoveFirst 
i = 0 
With Me.lbx_SSM 
    .Clear 
        Do 
        .AddItem 
        .List(i, 0) = XL_RSet![ID] 
        .List(i, 1) = XL_RSet![Unit] 
        .List(i, 2) = XL_RSet![Begin Time] ***Etc for other columns 
    i = i + 1 
    XL_RSet.MoveNext 
    Loop Until XL_RSet.EOF 
End With
```